# Blockly can console.log but can't interact with the workspace when using Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, blockly

I am having trouble accessing the javascript code generated by a Blockly component in my Vue app. I can console.log the workspace in a number of ways, but when attempting to generate the javascript code the workspace is undefined. Otherwise, Blockly works fine.

```
// Set workspace with reference to div and xml
this.workspace = Blockly.inject(this.$refs.blocklyDiv, {
   toolbox: this.$refs.tools
});
// another way to access the workspace
var workspace = Blockly.JavaScript.workspaceToCode();
// however,
console.log(this.workspace); // and
console.log(a);
```

both print a "Blockly.WorkspaceSvg {…}" // object

```
var code = Blockly.JavaScript.workspaceToCode(this.workspace); // any implementation of a workspace
console.log(code);
```

always returns "...;" and 
"No workspace specified in workspaceToCode call.  Guessing."

I have tried setting a workspace var between the opening script tag and export default too which also allows for console.log(workspace) but fails on workspaceToCode(workspace);

If I remove Vue, it works.
Do I need to build Blockly around my Vue instance??

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved -

This was related to using custom blocks.